# One click deployment from one office 365 site to other office site

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

I have requirement to deploy all my custom files on another office 365. Is there any way to do that ?

I have some html files,Js and Css files. I am using those html files in SharePoint page as content editor web part.

So if i want to give those files to my client then what i can do except giving them all files and asked them to add these files to their style library ?

Like we can do this using Visual Studio for SharePoint server by creating modules and when feature activates all file will be on style library.

So is there any way to achieve this on office 365 SharePoint site ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PNP model. You can use code or Powershell to deploy sites and and files. https://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices